# Get clicked view from onItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-layout

I am currently designing a store for a game and am facing a problem with the list of items to buy:

I have a *ListView* containing *RelativeLayouts* as items - in each *RelativeLayout* are two inner *RelativeLayouts*, with the items in them.

I want to find out if the user clicks on *BUY* in item1 or item2 - but I found no way to get this in an *onItemClickListener*.
The problem is, if I use *onClickListener* instead of *onItemClickListener*, I have the item (one or two), but not the row - so I always have either the row or the column.

Basically, I need to get the ID of the actually clicked Item from within the *onItemClickedListener* - is there any way I can do this?

[image: Sketch of Layout]

Comment: Do your list items can be clicked too or is just your buy button clickable? If both can be clicked you will have to make a custom onClickListener

Comment: I can catch both, clicks on the ListItems and button-clicks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a Tag to your Button (button.setTag(position)) in the Adapter´s *getView()* and then in onClickListener call view.getTag() to retrive an index

Comment: Can I be sure that the _onItemClickListener_ is ALWAYS called before the _onClickListener_? (if I understood you right, that would be necessary)

Comment: you should not add onItemClickListener to your ListView. The only Thing you should do is in the adapter class in getView() method write relativeLayout.setOnClickListener() and using an interface call a method from the main class. And do not forget,your relativeLayouts should have focusableInTouchMode set true

Comment: But I need to get the row of the item that was clicked - for that, I DO need the onItemClickListener, or is there another way?

Comment: don't setTag in onItemClickListener, you have to set tag from listview adapter. You will need to create custom listview adapter and then in public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  just add button.setTag(position);

Comment: that´s actually an awesome idea, i am gonna try that

Answer (score 0):

You should add onClickListner to your Child RelativeLayouts.Do it from your adapter getView method.

Comment: And how do I get the row of the clicked button? (position in the _ListView_)

Answer (score 0):

you set `onClickListener` to your buy Button. To the buy button you can attach tag of the position and retreive it in its `onClick` method.

Inside `getView()`

```
btnBuy.setOnClickListener(this);
btnBuy.setTag(position);
```

in `onClick` method

```
int position=Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
```

Comment: Can I be sure that the _onItemClickListener_ is ALWAYS called before the _onClickListener_? (if I understood you right, that would be necessary)

Comment: Yes. OnItemClick of the listView will be called before its child views get onClick.